# Is this "word wrap" issue?

Tags: css, stylesheet, word-wrap

I have an issue with word warp in some of my pages. For example, http://www.edpair.com/our-principles/

the word "achievement" was 'cut off'. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add meaningful code (the webpage source)  here. Don't just link to the site - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors if it's changed or goes down. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with `&nbsp`. Replace them with regular spaces and, if you want, you can add

```
text-align: justify;
```

to simulate the current alignment